# django.template.base.TemplateSyntaxError: default requires 2 arguments, 1 provided

Tags: python, django, django-templates, frontend, django-template-filters

I am trying to use django's built in 'default' filter using this code

```
<title>{{ title|default :"nothing" }}</title>
```

But it gives me the following exception

> django.template.base.TemplateSyntaxError: default requires 2 arguments, 1 provided

I am using the following settings for my Template Backend

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            str(APPS_DIR.path('templates')),
        ],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug': DEBUG,
            'loaders': [
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
            ],
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'allauth.account.context_processors.account',
                'allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

My editor marks the code as invalid, but i check like a thousand of times
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/

Where this is given as example:

```
{{ value|default:"nothing" }}
```

I also tried to change the name of title var, to make sure it is not a reserved keyword.

Comment: Read this might help https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/m4w-RNt-DOg

Comment: unforunatly that did not help, as i am actually using quotes for values, "nothing"

Comment: I hate to ask...but are you sure that line is the culprit? Do you have any other filters or tempate tags in that template? Can you show more of your template in your question?

Comment: Is there a `value` object in your context?

Comment: @mevius I am not sure and i dont think it is the breaking point, thats why i postet my template config. The template itself only loads the shown libs, [...] is only HTML-Code then i try using the filter. It got to be somewhere else, but i dont know where to look.

Comment: @DanielRoseman no, the value|default snippet is actually an django example, i am struggeling with the title stuff at the start, also the title is not an object its simply not passed in context.

Comment: If the title is not passed, how are you expecting it to work?

Comment: If no title is passed it should render the string "nothing". I tested with set title in context, and it works. Can i mark comments as correct answers?

Comment: Check this once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168117/custom-filter-needs-two-arguments

Comment: This works `{{ unknonw_var|default:"My default" }}`.

So your code should work. Are you 100% sure that the code bugs on that line? `<title>{{ title|default:"nothing" }}</title>`

Comment: @François i actually do not know what causes the error, if you say that unknown vars should be replaced too, the error still persits. But I dont know where i can lookup that error, as i don't have any custom filters applied nor changed the basic ones. As i said my editor marks this line as false or "incorrect". Maybe i am missing to load something?

Comment: "my editor marks this line as false or "incorrect"" But does it work in your browser? If you comment that line out, does that change anything?

Comment: If the value is not set/not defined in the Context Django does not render the template and throws the above mentioned error.

Comment: If the value is Set, e.g. to None, then it returns the "nothing" text, which was defined as default.

Comment: That's really weird since in my case `unknown_var` wasn't in the context. I'd say, create a custom template tag with `None` as default in it: `def my_default(value=None)`

Comment: Thanks, i think i will actually go for the custom tag. Unfortunately this only happens with my new setup, so i was wondering if there are any settings to change or control this behavior. The same code works in a different project of mine, as aspected, too.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Make sure you don't have a space after the colon.

This is correct:

```
{{ title|default:"nothing" }}
```

This throws an exception:

```
{{ title|default: "nothing" }}
```

Comment: Seriously in a fault tollerant system like Django, a space borks things up?   Much love the Django team, I'm sure all work very hard and charge nothing for your labors, so thanks for all your hard work.  But a space, really?

Comment: space was not the issue for me but i'll accept the answer, as it seems many people face that issue

Comment: @Iwan1993 If your issue was different, could you please post another answer explaining what was the problem? This might help others :)

Comment: honestly, after a day i decided to restart the project - as i made up several tests from ootb and everything worked fine. Must have messed the configuration elsewhere. :(

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
{{ title|default_if_none:"nothing" }}
```

**default_if_none** will display the given string if the variable is 'None'.

**default** will display the string if the variable evaluates to False, ie empty strings, empty lists etc

Also make sure you send **title** variable in your context , if not you must use **default_if_none**

Answer (score 0):

With [Django template filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#built-in-filter-reference), putting space either before or after `:` gets error as shown below:

```
             # Space (Error)
                ↓ ↓
{{ title|default : "nothing" }}
```

So, don't put any space there not to get error as shown below:

```
          # No space (No error)
               ↓ ↓
{{ title|default:"nothing" }}
```

In addition, putting space either before or after `|` doesn't get error:

```
     # Space (No error)
        ↓ ↓
{{ title | default:"nothing" }}
```