# Rendering dynamic variable in a django template

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to render dynamic Url in Django template as follows
`<a href={{'jibambe_site_detail/'|add: site.id}}>{{ site }}</a>`. This however is returning a `TemplateSyntaxError at /jibambe_sites/
add requires 2 arguments, 1 provided`. What am I missing or how should I render this dynamic URL, I want it to produce something like `jibambe_site_detail/1`

Comment: You should really use the `url` tag, but have you tried `href="/jibambe_site_detail/{{ site.id }}"`?

Comment: @schwobaseggl Yes I have. The result is just `jibambe_site_detail/`

Comment: That would mean that either `site` is None or not in the context or does not have the attribute `id`.

Comment: @schwobaseggl but `site` is not None since I am printing a list of sites and `site.name` is returning a value. `<li><a href='jibambe_site_detail/'{{site}}>{{ site.name }}</a> </li>`

Comment: @schwobaseggl from your comment that I should use `url` tag, I have been able to resolve the issue as follows `<a href={% url 'site_details' pk=site.id %}>{{ site.name }}</a>`

Comment: That looks much better! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @schwobaseggl comment, I was able to add a dynamic `url` variable as follows `<a href={% url 'site_details' pk=site.id %}>{{ site.name }}</a>`
then in the `urls.py` `urlpatterns`, I gave the `path` to `jibambe_site_details` a name `path('jibambe_site_detail/<slug:pk>', JibambeSitesDetails.as_view(), name='site_details'),`

Answer (score 1):

OP's strategy changed on this one but OP's original error seems to be because of the **space after colon**.

Use `add:site.id` instead of `add: site.id`

See a similar question about `default` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35261015/1526703)